# Como acrescentar um valor em um campo vazio no MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Estou rodando uma `query` que precisa pegar as **5 primeiras linhas** com `limit 5`. Porém, existem ocasiões em que irão retornar menos de 5 linhas. O valor vem vazio, nem `NULL`, nem `0`.

Tento fazer um `case when`, mas continua retornando vazio. Alguém sabe como eu posso resolver isso?

Minha `query` esta abaixo:

```
select case when defail5  then 0 else defail5 end 
  from (select failure, count(failure) as defail5 
          from reparo.falhas_consolidadas 
         where  brand2 in ('LBG_DKT') 
           and week = 'week-5-16' 
         group by failure 
         order by count(failure) desc limit 4 offset 3) as tb1;
```

Comment: Você não consegue tratar isso no seu programa?

Comment: Qual campo vem vazio? Tente explicar melhor sua pergunta.

Comment: tudo vem vazio,

Comment: Diego, só pra entender melhor, a query tem que retornar sempre 5 linhas, é isso? Quando tiver só 3 linhas tem que retornar mais duas linhas com valor 0? Tenta colocar um exemplo do que espera que retorne na sua query nessas situações.